# Using both multiprocessing and multithreading in a Python script to speed up execution

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have the following range of subnets: 10.106.44.0/24 - 10.106.71.0/24. I am writing a Python script to ping each IP in all the subnets. To speed up this script I am trying to use both multiprocessing and multithreading. I am creating a new process for each subnet and creating a new thread to ping each host in that subnet. I would like to ask two questions:

1. Is this the best approach for this problem?
2. If yes, how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Since you just pinging (mostly IO) and not doing any long computation, you can just use a thread pool.

Comment: But if I run it on all 12 cores that I have on my server, will it not run in 1/12th the time?

Comment: You can set the pool size to be 12 (as the number of cores you have)
Starting up processes/threads has a big overhead. By using thread-pool, you initialize the threads once, and they are being reused.

Comment: Python `multiprocessing` also supports creating a process pool (if you really need a new process)

Comment: Multiprocessing comes with interesting design challenges and costs - all data sent between processes has to be pickled/unpickled, and there are no global variables to share info. There are many questions on here along the lines of ‘why doesn’t my multiprocessing code run 12x faster on 12 cores? Or even ‘why is my multiprocessing code slower than non-multiprocessing. Threads are much easier to use, and for I/O-bound work are very effective.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to use threading. You can try creating a thread pool whose size is the total number of pings you have to do, but ultimately I believe that this will not do much better than using a thread pool size equal to the number of CPU cores you have (explanation below). Here is a comparison both ways using threading and multiprocessing:

**ThreadPoolExecutor (255 threads)**

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import os
import platform
import subprocess
import time

def ping_ip(ip_address):
    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower() == 'windows' else '-c'
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(f"ping {param} 1 {ip_address}", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
        if 'unreachable' in output:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    except Exception:
            return False


def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    ip_addresses = ['192.168.1.154'] * 255
    #with ThreadPoolExecutor(os.cpu_count())) as executor: # uses number of CPU cores
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(len(ip_addresses)) as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(ping_ip, ip_addresses))
        #print(results)
        print(time.time() - t1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
2.049474000930786
```

You can try experimenting with *fewer* threads (`max_workers` argument to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor). See: [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

**I found that running 8 threads, which is the number of cores that I had, did just about as well (timing: 2.2745485305786133). I believe the reason for this is that despite pinging being an I/O-related task, the call to subprocess must be creating internally a new process that uses a fair amount of CPU and therefore the concurrency is somewhat processor-limited.**

**ProcessPoolExecutor (8 cores)**

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os
import platform
import subprocess
import time

def ping_ip(ip_address):
    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower() == 'windows' else '-c'
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(f"ping {param} 1 {ip_address}", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
        if 'unreachable' in output:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    except Exception:
            return False


def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    ip_addresses = ['192.168.1.154'] * 255
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(ping_ip, ip_addresses))
        #print(results)
        print(time.time() - t1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
2.509838819503784
```

**Note that on my Linux system you have to be a superuser to issue a ping command.**